# How to fill the remaining viewport height with a Sidebar under a Navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This describes the problem:
https://www.codeply.com/p/YFfrDC5Bz2

I want to stretch the sidebar over the remaining viewport height so that the  footer is visible all the time, while the bootstrap 4 navbar could be any height. Is there a way to do this?

Another way to say It is I don't want the sidebar to scroll at all while only the content is scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this style to your side footer element `.sidebar h3.mt-auto` which you need show all time.

```
.sidebar h3.mt-auto {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I want the whole sidebar to be stretched over the whole viewport height. I just added the footer to show the problem. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I would try giving the `<h3>` that has your footer text a class like `sidebar-footer`.
In the CSS give it:

```css
.sidebar-footer {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I tested that code in the link you sent and got this:
[image]

Let me know if that's what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using a grid layout, I might do something like this:

```
.main
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10rem 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr;
    position: relative;
}

.main > *
{   box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

#nav
{ grid-column: 1/3;
grid-row: 1/2;

}

.sidebar
{   grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.content.flex-fill
{   grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    
}
```

It's not 100%, The only thing is you mention the "variable height" nav.  If you know for sure what the nav's height is, then in the .sidebar class, you can change height to something like calc(100vh - NAVHEIGHT).

Comment: That's why I mentioned variable height or well responsive or whatever. In bootstrap this value NAVHEIGHT does not exist!

Comment: NAVHEIGHT was just something you could fill in for whatever the height is.  In you're example, it's 56px tall, so in that case you'd change it to calc(100vh - 56px).  But for a variable height one, I can only see using JS to dynamically resize it...

Comment: Not It's simply not possible to define It, in your browser the navbar may have a height of 56px, however on another browser It can be different. Especially when the navbar  can collapse.